# Disable shadows for one camera in Gazebo Sim

Tags: gazebo, simulation, camera

I have a Gazebo Harmonic simulation, in which I have some lights which cast shadows. I would like to keep those shadows for the overall simulation (i.e. the camera of the GUI), but disable all shadows for a specific camera sensor.

On first sight, this does not seem possible, as shadows are a property of lights rather than of a camera.

I also thought of setting the visibility flags, but it seems lights do not have those.

Anyone knows a way to do this?

Or, alternatively: is it possible to disable all shadows server-side (where the camera sensor is rendered) while enabling shadows client-side (for the gui renderer)?

Answer (score 1):

I think an option could be to implement a plugin that registers a callback to the [`PreRender` event](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/a88340b0d535905765aeaa41aab7b4d177fa6522/examples/plugin/rendering_plugins/RenderingServerPlugin.cc#L38), which retrieves the lights from the scene and disables their shadow casting.